# Ebay API - GetSellerTransactions not returning all transactions

Tags: java, transactions, ebay-api

I have about 40 transactions in ebay. But GetSellerTransactions is only returning 16. Here is my request and the version is 981.

```
    GetSellerTransactionsCall call = new GetSellerTransactionsCall( context );
    GetSellerTransactionsRequestType  request = new GetSellerTransactionsRequestType();
    request.setIncludeFinalValueFee(true);
    request.setDetailLevel(new DetailLevelCodeType[]{
            DetailLevelCodeType.RETURN_ALL,
            DetailLevelCodeType.ITEM_RETURN_ATTRIBUTES
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. GetSellerTransactions returns transactions for a max of 30 days. To get all transactions, I had to make multiple requests by setting setModTimeFrom and setModTimeTo values in the requests.